# CDN for Font Awesome 4.0 not serving font files

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I've been using Font Awesome for a little while now, and was updating to 4.0 today. I decided to use the BootstrapCDN this time, and I've run into problems. The icons aren't being displayed despite using the new class names.

The CSS file is getting pulled down fine, but when I look at developer tools in Chrome the fonts aren't being served. Based on the relative path to the font within the CSS file (src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.0');), I was able to test the link and download the font:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.0

So the link is correct (of course). Anyone know why the font isn't being served?

Comment: should be fixed. open an issue on github/maxcdn/bootstrap-cdn if you are still seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do more than just use the new class names. Did you make sure that you added the `fa` class as well?

Comment: Thank you.. i had the same issue but turns out that i had just replace 'icon-' to 'fa-'. Forgot to add the 'fa' class.